# sIFR letters narrower than original font

Tags: sifr, typography

I am using corporate(expensive) font-family Gotham. 
The problem i'm having is that the sIFR font is slightly narrower that the original fonts which doesn't do the font justice.

Is there a reason for this? 
Is there anything i can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, but it sounds like a Flash issue, not immediately a sIFR issue.